# Alternative to use of udevadm command

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I have a script that uses the command `udevadm` to get informations about a /dev device, the information required for my script is the `ID_SERIAL` value because I want to filter the `tty's` devices that represents a specific product connected to the USB port. The problem is, the udevadm version of the udevm present on the environment is `128` and this version of `udevadm` don't have the query `property` avaiable. How can I filter the device connected on usb's ports in another way?

EDIT 1
**Command.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev);do
    (syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}";
     echo "syspath = $syspath";
     devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)";
     [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]]&& continue;
     echo "Passou";
     eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)";
     [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && continue;
     temporario=${ID_SERIAL,,};
     if [[ $temporario == *"ManufacturerName"* ]];
     then 
        echo "/dev/$devname";
     fi);
done;
```

Comment: Am I right to assume you can't update udev in your environment?

Comment: If you can't get `udevadm` to filter exactly how you want, maybe you can use other tools such as `grep`, `sed`, or `awk` to further filter the output from `udevadm`.

Comment: I can not update the environment.

Comment: edit your Q to include a small sample output of your `udevadm` cmd. This assumes that `ID_SERIAL` value is in that output. If it isn't then you need to find another tool that can return that value. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to use the output of `dmesg`? When I plug in my serial port, I get this output:

```
[332144.226566] usb 1-2.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[332144.302766] usb 1-2.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[332144.302770] usb 1-2.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[332144.512664] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[332144.512679] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[332144.512691] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[332144.522042] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[332144.522060] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[332144.522090] pl2303 1-2.1.2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[332144.523681] usb 1-2.1.2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

The last line mentions `ttyUSB0`, and you can relate this to to the `1-2.1.2` if you want to identify the remove-event too:

```
[332342.342682] usb 1-2.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[332342.342891] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[332342.342903] pl2303 1-2.1.2:1.0: device disconnected
```

Another possibility would be to use the `inotify` system, where you could receive a notification when the drive is plugged in. Check [this article on how to use the system](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj05t6DwcbNAhUDC5AKHTnaBkUQFggvMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftecharena51.com%2Findex.php%2Finotify-tools-example%2F&usg=AFQjCNFhHdR26ab9pScJFLV68j42U4Ao_Q&sig2=VCGsP31pax5lXVMoZR8WNw).